# Swift / CollectionView disappears randomly with Custom Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` on a `UIView`. The screen is invoked with a custom segue:

```
    import UIKit

class CustomUIStoryBoardSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let firstVC = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        let secondVC = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height


        secondVC.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVC, aboveSubview: firstVC)

        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in // set animation duration

            firstVC.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVC.frame, 0.0, 0.0) // old screen stay

            secondVC.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVC.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0) // new screen strave from right to left

            }) { (Finished) -> Void in
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController,
                    animated: false,
                    completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

The screen is called by a button on a menu. If I call this screen 10-20 times in a row, 5-10x the `UICollectionView` is missing. If I disable the custom segue, everything is fine and the `UICollectionView` is present all the time.

What am I missing or what is wrong with this segue?

Comment: the problem seems to be gone, if  I set the animation to duration from 0.3 to 0.1 -> But why...

Comment: You can set the simulator to run animation in slow motion, maybe you can see what is happening while it's moving

Comment: thank you for the tipp, but there is nothing to see. the new screen comes just without collectionview and it will not be loaded unless I call the screen again